# JS object/JSON key wildcard

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, object

I have an object that is evaluated from JSON that looks like this:

```js
{
    "foo %s": "bar %s",
    "Hello %s world %s.": "We have multiple %s %s."
}
```

Using this object and the following inputs, I am trying to achieve something like this:

- `foo bar` -> matches `foo %s` -> `bar bar`
- `Hello foo world bar.` -> matches `Hello %s world %s.` -> `We have multiple foo bar`

So far I have the following code which works for one `%s` and only if it is surrounded by spaces.

```
let str = "input here";
let a = {
        "foo %s": "bar %s",
        "Hello %s world %s.": "We have multiple %s %s."
    },
    p = str.split(" "),
    result;
for (let j in p) { // loop indices
    let pp = p.map(u => u); // create local array
    pp[j] = "%s"; //replace index with %s
    if (a[pp.join(" ")]) { // check if this is in the object
        result = a[pp.join(" ")].replace("%s", p[j]); // join the array and replace %s from the result
        break;
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your object to [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and then [execute them in a call to `String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Example with a single, defined, replacement operation:

```js
console.log('Hello foo world bar.'.replace(/^Hello (.*?) world (.*?) bar\.$/, 'We have multiple $1 $2.'))
// Output: We have multiple foo bar.
```

Here we basically match against the whole string - if it matches the pattern, the whole contents will get replaced.

As you can see, to achieve this, you would need to transform the `"Hello %s world %s."` into `/^Hello (.*?) world (.*?)\.$/` (with the `(.*?)` defining a non-greedy capture group containing any characters) and the `"We have multiple %s %s."` into `"We have multiple $1 $2."` (with `$x` referring to the `x`-th capture group's contents).

So you could have a function like this:

```js
function replaceTemplates (str, templates) {
  // This helper function escapes any characters which would have a special
  // meaning in the regexp otherwise. $& is the match as a whole, so it replaces
  // each of these characters with themselves prepended by a backlash.
  const escapeRegExp = s => s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
  
  for (const [template, replacement] of Object.entries(templates)) {
    // We create a regexp from the template, replacing every %s with (.*?), wrapping it
    // in ^ and $ (start/end of string) and escaping all the other special characters.
    const re = new RegExp('^' + escapeRegExp(template).replace(/%s/g, '(.*?)') + '$')
    
    if (re.test(str)) {
      // To get the correct string for the right side of the string replace method,
      // we have to replace each %s in the replacement string by $1, $2, $3 etc. and
      // also replace single $ signs by $$ because the $ has a special meaning as shown
      // above, and then we can call the actual replace and return the result. But since
      // a $ in the replacement has to be escaped as just explained, we have to write
      // FOUR $ signs to get TWO at the end.
      let i = 1 // This is used as counter in the following replacing operations for $x
      const reReplacement = replacement
        .replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')
        .replace(/%s/g, () => '$' + i++) // By using a function, we can make $x dynamic
      
      return str.replace(re, reReplacement)
    }
  }
  
  return str
}

const templates = {
  'foo %s': 'bar %s',
  'Hello %s world %s.': 'We have multiple %s %s.'
}

console.log(replaceTemplates('foo bar', templates)) // Output: bar bar
console.log(replaceTemplates('Hello foo world bar.', templates)) // Output: We have multiple foo bar.
```

By the way: If `pp = p.map(u => u)` is supposed to create a copy, I'd suggest `pp = p.slice()` or just `pp = [...p]` instead.